# Enabling verboseGC on WebSphere Application Server

Tags: garbage-collection, websphere

I have an issue while enabling verboseGC. I have  8 JVMs (clustered) and out of those, 3 JVMs have been already enabled for verboseGC. I am now enabling verboseGC on the remaining 5 JVMs.

Once I enabled verboseGC at below path (on the 'Runtime' tab) , I have restarted the JVMs.
`Application servers > applicationservername > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine`.

But when I look for verboseGC logs in the `native_stderr.log` file, I don't see anything logged. When I went back to the above path, I found that the 'Verbose garbage collection' setting on the 'Runtime' tab was unchecked automatically.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? What was done to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Changes made on the 'Runtime' tab do not persist across restarts of WebSphere Application Server. Any such changes are applied to the currently running JVM process, but are lost when the process is restarted. For the VerboseGC setting to be applied permanently, update the setting under the Configuration tab. Then restart the server for the changes to take effect.

As for the log not being written, verboseGC output is written to `native_stderr.log` on AIX, Linux, & Windows and to `native_stdout.log` on Solaris & HP-UX. If you are using Solaris or HP-UX, you have to set Generic JVM Arguments for the logging to work correctly. Refer to this [IBM Document](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21114927) for details.